# Implicit not applicable

Tags: scala

I am practicing to use implicit parameters, as far as I have learned from scala website:

> eligible are all identifiers x that can be accessed at the point of the method call without a prefix and that denote an implicit definition or an implicit parameter.

So I wrote the following piece of code:

```
  class Env(str: String) {
    override def toString = str
  }
  object ImplicitUser {
    def apply(implicit env: Env) {
      println(env.toString)
    }
  }
  object Run {
    def apply() {
      implicit val myEnv = new Env("abc")
      ImplicitUser() // compiler error
    }
  }
```

The error confused me:

- `myEnv` can be accessed, without a prefix
- `myEnv` is an implicit value

So why doesn't compiler automatically fill `myEnv` into `ImplicitUser.apply`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have explicitly called `apply` method with empty parameters list. You should remove brackets for parameters group with implicit parameters, but you can't implicitly call `apply` method without brackets.

You have 2 options:

1) Call `apply` explicitly without brackets:

```
ImplicitUser.apply
```

2) Add addition parameters group to `apply` method:

```
object ImplicitUser {
  def apply()(implicit env: Env) {
    ...
  }
}

...

  ImplicitUser()
```